# SQL GROUP BY error issue

Tags: sql, group-by

I'm trying to write a code that group everything by organization/corporate number, 
but I get an error. Can anyone see what the reason is for the error?
The data looks like:

[image: DATA]

This is the code

```
select *, Differens = (nullif(Intrastat,0)-Moms)/ nullif(moms,0) 
from 
#Tabell1
Group by Orgnr
order by Orgnr, Månad
```

The error i get is the following:

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 23 Column '#Tabell1.Tillnr' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Comment: When you are gouping rows, all the collumns in the select must be in the order by or in an aggregate function (SUM, COUNT, MIN... etc...)

Comment: Take into account you are merging a bunch of rows in a single one, you must indicate what to do to merge the different values in all the columns you SELECT.

Comment: `select *` with `group by` is definitely a bad sign.

Answer (score 0):

All the columns in the select must be in the group by clausole: in this case you have a select *, so you have to do **group by [table primary key or superkey]**

(Work with PostgreSql)

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, when grouping, you can either select fields that you are grouping on or you must apply an aggregate (min, max, avg, count, etc...)